# Как выровнять список

Tags: html, css

Есть список `li` нужно выровнять его относительно `list-style-type`

```css
.list{
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
.list li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.list li:before {
    content: "㋛";
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
       <div class="text">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li>Просматривать статистику покупок</li>
                    <li>Выводить денежные средства, когда удобно <br>собственнику или получать их моментально <br>после оплаты</li>
                    <li>Дополнять объявление новыми данными</li>
                    <li>Общаться с оппонентами через чат</li>
                </ul>
       </div>
```

Как можно увидеть второй элемент `li` не выровнен, часть его находится на уровне с маркером, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например добавит `display: flex;` для `li`

```css
.list{
    margin: auto;
}
.list li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex; /* добавить */
}
.list li:before {
    content: "㋛";
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li>Просматривать статистику покупок</li>
                    <li>Выводить денежные средства, когда удобно <br>собственнику или получать их моментально <br>после оплаты</li>
                    <li>Дополнять объявление новыми данными</li>
                    <li>Общаться с оппонентами через чат</li>
                </ul>
       </div>
```